# Inserting data into a sql server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

Is there a relatively simple way to insert multiple rows into a table in which the data being inserted comes from both a select statement and hard-coded data?

For example,

```
insert into tblB 
  (field1, field2, field3) 
values 
  ( 950, select fieldA, fieldB from tblA )
```

...where 950 is a hard-coded value and `fieldA` and `fieldB` come from `tblA`

Comment: It's just a tiny change in your syntax. Put the hard-coded value in the SELECT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
insert into tblB 
(field1, field2, field3) 
select 950, fieldA, fieldB 
from tblA
```

Comment: @chama: 950 is a static value, it doesn't need to exist in the table

Answer (score 0):

insert into tablename(fieldname1,fieldname2,...)values(value1,value2,....)